# Show that $\phi_{y,\epsilon} \in D(\mathbb{R^m})$

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, distribution-theory

For a fixed $y$

$$\phi_{y,\epsilon}(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         \exp(-\frac{\epsilon^2}{\epsilon^2-|x-y|^2}) & \mbox{if $|x-y| \lt \epsilon$};\\
        0 & \mbox{otherwise}.\end{array} \right. $$

Show that $\phi_{y,\epsilon} \in D(\mathbb{R^m})$

I am unable to show this. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You could argume that $\exp\{\frac{1}{1-x^2}\}$ is the integral of its derivative, and proceed to write as multiple integrals of derivatives using integration by parts. All you have to know is that the derivatives are bounded and tend to $0$ at $x=\pm 1$. Then you can compose with $|x-y|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show by induction that all derivatives of $f(t)=\exp(-1/t)$ are of the form
$f^{(n)}(t)=p_n(1/t)f(t)$ with polynomials $p_n$.Then conclude that $f$ extended by $0$ for $t\le 0$ is a smooth function and note that your function is a  composition of $f$ with a polynomial.